# Arrange divs in an ASC or DESC order based on child node's numeric value?

Tags: jquery

How to use jquery change each html wrap one of inner tag value by asc and desc?

```
<div class="wrap_0">
    <div class="sort_by">0</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap_1">
    <div class="sort_by">3</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap_2">
    <div class="sort_by">1</div>
</div>
```

change to

```
<div class="wrap_0">
    <div class="sort_by">0</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap_2">
    <div class="sort_by">1</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap_1">
    <div class="sort_by">3</div>
</div>
```

Now I'm only find the way to sort one wrap inner div

```
var items = $('.wrap div').get();
items.sort(function(a,b){
    var keyA = $(a).text();
    var keyB = $(b).text();

if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
});
var wrap = $('.wrap');
$.each(items, function(i, sort_by){
    wrap.append(sort_by);
});
```

Comment: I would be nice if you post the jQuery code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I have update the question, I can't figure how to do it..... any clue??

Comment: Your question title was too confusing man, I've changed it, please accept edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution which will work even if the elements aren't at the root of the body or aren't the first elements of their container :

```
var s = $('[class^=wrap_]').get().sort(function(a,b){
   return parseInt($('.sort_by', a).html(),10)-parseInt($('.sort_by', b).html(),10)
});
for (var i=s.length;i>0;i--) $(s[i]).insertAfter(s[0]);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uwizem/1/edit)

Comment: Note that I didn't optimize the code. If you have hundreds elements to sort, it might be interesting to cache the parsed values.

Comment: ... I'm newbie it is difficult for me to understand this code, but I'm try to figure ing...  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It gets all elements with class starting with `wrap_`, finds the child div with class `sort_by` and compares each. Once sorted, it iterates over each and appends it to a parent/wrapper element (in this case `body`) in the correct order:

```
$("div[class^='wrap_']").get().sort(function(a, b) {
   var idx = parseInt($(a).find(".sort_by").text(),10);
   var idx2 = parseInt($(b).find(".sort_by").text(),10);
   return idx > idx2;
}).each(function() {
   $(this).appendTo("body");
});
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4U2V/1/)

Comment: You should be careful when comparing texts : "11" < "3"

Comment: Any idea how I could make this work with input values rather than .html()? I tried using .val() and it's not working. See updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/E4U2V/3/